# Google Sheet Script to import rows from (sheet1) and increase row intervals on target (sheet2)

Tags: google-apps-script, import, google-sheets

I'm trying to import data from a Sheet and "set values" imported on target increasing rows intervals every 9 rows.
I'm trying this script (below) but it doesn't work correctly when importing. The writing works correctly.

How can I do this? Thank you for your attention. 
example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xFtfiHZqd7JhIAkwxJ8JVnqx-21d2cj43nmHnvWLOpg/edit?usp=sharing

```
function abc()
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA");
  var startData = 3;
  var endData = 1000;  
  while (startData < endData) {
    var content = sourceSheet.getRange(startData, 1);
    startData += 1;  
  }

  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Target");  
  var startTarget = 3;
  var endTarget = 1000;  
  while (startTarget < endTarget) {
    targetSheet.getRange(startTarget, 1).setValue(content);
    startTarget += 9;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the import fails to work as you expect is because your code overwrites the existing value of `content` within every iteration of the `while` loop. To be honest, I'm surprised the Apps Script code editor doesn't flag your code for inefficiencies and recommend you use batch read  methods.

You can eliminate the read `while` loop by using the [`getSheetValues()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetValues(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)):

```
// Read the content data into an array of arrays:
// content[0] = first row; content[2][0] = value in first column in 3rd row
var numRows = endData - startData;
var numCols = 1;
var content = sourceSheet.getSheetValues(startData, 1, numRows, numCols);
```

There is however no batch method for acquiring/writing to a non-contiguous range, so your incrementing write does need a loop. Rather than a `while` loop, a `for` loop can be easier to implement correctly:

```
// Write all data from the content array to the target starting row,
// and then every 9th row thereafter. (e.g. rows 3, 12, 21, 30....)
for(var row = 0; row < content.length; ++row) {
  targetSheet.getRange(startTarget + 9 * row, 1).setValue(content[row][0]);
}
```

If you truly do want to discard 8/9ths of `content`, then the corresponding `while` loop would be:

```
var row = 0;
while (startTarget < endTarget && row < content.length) {
  targetSheet.getRange(startTarget, 1).setValue(content[row][0];
  ++row;
  startTarget += 9;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!
I'm starting with scripts, thank you for teaching me this!